# JSP cif not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have this code in my jsp file:

```
<body>
    <c:if test="${!isActivityVP && isBuy && isOwner}">
        Hello
    </c:if>
</body>
```

`isActivityVP` and `isBuy` and `isOwner` are all boolean values

when I visit the page, however, I got this in the html:

```
<body>
    <c:if test="false">
        Hello
    </c:if>
</body>
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `jstlxxx.jar` into `WEB-INF/lib` and add  `<%@ taglib %>` directive in JSP page.

```
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<body>
    <c:if test="${!isActivityVP && isBuy && isOwner}">
        Hello
    </c:if>
</body>
```